# Properties of lower and upper sums Riemann integration in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ and $|f(x)|\leqslant M$ on $[a,b]$, $P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, and $c\in[a,b]$. Argue that
>   $$\left|\mathcal U_{P\cup\{c\}}(f) - \mathcal U_P(f) \right|\leqslant 2M\cdot\operatorname{Mesh}(P) $$
>   and
>   $$\left|\mathcal L_{P\cup\{c\}}(f) - \mathcal L_P(f) \right|\leqslant 2M\cdot\operatorname{Mesh}(P).$$

I understand that $2M\cdot\operatorname{Mesh}(P)$ is the 'largest' rectangle but I don't really understand how to go about proving this. It's not homework, I am really just practicing proofs, so I could use some help.

Comment: You need to use the boundedness of $f$ to bound the difference in the upper sum of a partition and that partition with an additional point. Observe that $|x_j-c|\leqslant \operatorname{Mesh}(P)$ for any $x_j\in P$, and of course $|f(c)|\leqslant M$.

Comment: I'm still not sure what to do